# Error in Oracle Code with non-equijoin operation

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm brand new to stack overflow so I apologize if I did something wrong when I posted this.
I'm having some problems with this block of code. I believe that there are problems with my joins.

```
UPDATE   rental_item ri
SET      rental_item_price =
      (SELECT   p.amount
       FROM     price p INNER JOIN common_lookup cl1
       ON       p.price_type = cl1.common_lookup_id CROSS JOIN rental r
                CROSS JOIN common_lookup cl2 
       WHERE    p.item_id = ri.item_id AND ri.rental_id = r.rental_id
       AND      ri.rental_item_type = cl2.common_lookup_id
       AND      cl1.common_lookup_code = cl2.common_lookup_code
       AND      r.check_out_date
                  BETWEEN p.start_date AND p.end_date);
```

This block of code is supposed to fill the "RENTAL_ITEM_PRICE" column with data from the "AMOUNT" column using the criteria specified above. I can't remove any of the criteria in the WHERE and AND statements.

```
RENTAL_ITEM_ID RENTAL_ITEM_PRICE AMOUNT
-------------- ----------------- ------
  1001                             5
  1002                             5
  1003                             5
  1004                             5
  1005                             5
  1006                             5
  1007                             5
  1008                             5
  1009                             5
  1010                             3
  1011                             3
  1012                            10
  1013                            15
```

When I run the code it says that 13 rows were updated but as you can see no information is written. It also does not return any errors.

It should look like this:

```
RENTAL_ITEM_ID RENTAL_ITEM_PRICE     AMOUNT
-------------- ----------------- ----------
      1001                 5          5
      1002                 5          5
      1003                 5          5
      1004                 5          5
      1005                 5          5
      1006                 5          5
      1007                 5          5
      1008                 5          5
      1009                 5          5
      1010                 3          3
      1011                 3          3
      1012                10         10
      1013                15         15
```

Comment: Does the query return the expected values as a simple select? I'd suspect it just doesn't find any data, but can't guess why without seeing the data. Why are you doing cross joins then turning them back into inner joins via the `where` clause?

Comment: My guess is that the subquery is returning zero rows, so the values are being updated with `NULL`s.

Comment: @AlexPoole I tried to do a simple select statement to test it but it fails because some of the aliases are not properly defined without the UPDATE line. In regards to the data being missing every field referenced in the subquery contains information. So it does have data to pull from. I'm guessing that as Gordon Linoff mentioned the subquery is returning zeros. I think that the way the joins are written is causing a problem. Do either of you have a suggestion for how I could fix the subquery? Sorry I don't have a better way of asking my question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's my guess as well. I know that all of the columns referenced contain valid data but I'm guessing my joins or where clauses may be causing a problem. I believe the problem lies with the non-equijoin operation.

Comment: @kb4000 . . . Rather impossible for anyone over here to say.  Perhaps you could put an example on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry it is a fairly complex query so it's hard for me to come up with an example that is easier to understand but I will try.

Comment: The `ri` alias won't be defined, but you can just replace those three column references with actual values for a row you expect to update. But as that will presumably find no data it's just a starting point to debug. We can't do that for you without the tables and sample data, unfortunately.

Comment: You said every field referenced in the subquery contains information... just to check, none of them are null, including `p.end_date`?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole that fixed it. I did it as a simple SELECT statement with other values defined for the ri columns and turns out that data from a previous script was incorrect and was causing null values in p.end_date. How do I say thanks on here?

Comment: @kb4000 - I've turned it into an answer (see [the help centre!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)), which seems a bit artificial now but the alternative is to close the question as no longer reproducible and this might just be useful for someone else one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery is returning no rows, so the update is setting all the `rental_item_price` values to null. Running the subquery on its own - substituting actual values from the `rental_item` table in place of the `ri.*` columns as that alias won't exist whenyou just run the `select` part - is likely to show no data found.

If it does then you have to figure out which of your joins or conditions is incorrect, which is basic debugging, but you can start by removing filter conditions until some data appears, or checking the join conditions.

My initial guess - now confirmed - was that `price.end_date` might be null, which makes sense if you have active products and you aren't setting an artificial magic end date (like `9999-12-31`, for example, which will one day be part of the Y10K problem). The `between` clause would then fail to match anyway, since nothing is between a real date and null.

You can either set the end date to a magic value in your table, which many woul consider a nasty hack, or treat it as a magic future date as part of the query which isn't much better, or use the comparison date as the default:

```
r.check_out_date BETWEEN p.start_date
  AND COALESCE(p.end_date, r.check_out_date)
```

---

I'm not sure why you are using cross joins and then applying filter conditions, at least for the self-join for `common_lookup`; not really relevant to the question but from what I think it's doing I might have structured the subquery as:

```
SELECT p.amount
FROM rental r
CROSS JOIN common_lookup cl1
INNER JOIN common_lookup cl2
ON cl2.common_lookup_code = cl1.common_lookup_code
INNER JOIN price p 
ON p.price_type = cl2.common_lookup_id
AND r.check_out_date BETWEEN p.start_date
  AND COALESCE(p.end_date, r.check_out_date)
WHERE r.rental_id = ri.rental_id
AND cl1.common_lookup_id = ri.rental_item_type
AND p.item_id = ri.item_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this SQL is on the p.end_date.
end_date can be null. Thats why we need to add a value using NVL when this happens.
A solution for your problem is:

```
enter code here

UPDATE   rental_item ri
SET      rental_item_price =
(SELECT p.amount 
FROM price p 
INNER JOIN common_lookup cl1 
ON p.price_type = cl1.common_lookup_id CROSS JOIN rental r
CROSS JOIN common_lookup cl2 
WHERE p.item_id = ri.item_id AND ri.rental_id = r.rental_id 
AND ri.rental_item_type = cl2.common_lookup_id 
AND cl1.common_lookup_code = cl2.common_lookup_code 
AND r.check_out_date 
BETWEEN p.start_date AND NVL (p.end_date, TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1)));
```